# How to write a Regular Expression

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

I have seen that the regular expression for the set of strings beginning with $a$ and ending with $b$ is written as $a(a+b)^*b$

Can some one tell me how to write this

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean. $a(a+b)^*b$ is indeed a regular expression describing the set of strings over the alphabet $\{a,b\}$ that begin with $a$ and end with $b$. What is it that you want to write?

Comment: I want to know how it is written

Comment: How *what* is written? The regular expression is written $a(a+b)^*b$.